# How to display a UIButton in front of all views in UINavigationController?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uiwindow

I've got a `UIButton` that I'd like to display in the same position in front of all of the `viewControllers` of my `UINavigationController`, much in the same way that a `UINavigationBar` would - but in this case, I'd like the button to float in the lower-left corner of the screen, like so:

[image]

I could try manually adding it to each `viewController`, but I'd prefer to do it once and forget about it.

Adding the button as a subview to the `UIWindow` doesn't seem to work - it winds up behind the `rootViewController`.

**Update:** I've figured out a way to do it, but because it involves iOS 7, I can't post the solution here until the NDA is lifted. The good news is, it's fairly simple to accomplish this! I'll post something once it's OK to share.

Comment: make a UIView and add it on every VC

Comment: Right, but that's explicitly what I'm trying to avoid doing here. I'd like it to float in front of all view controllers, instead of having it move during the transition.

Comment: @bryanjclark iOS 7 NDA is lifted. What did you do?

Comment: @TomHamming I implemented custom UINavigationController transitions, and moved the button between view controllers during that transition.

Answer (score 0):

create a NSObject class `buttonPanel` and allocate the button and you can call the button panel as follow:

```
buttonPanel * buttonPanel = [[buttonPanel alloc] init];
buttonPanel.delegate = self;
[buttonPanel showButtonWithNavigationController:self.navigationController inView:self.parentViewController.view];
```

ButtonPanel class:

```
//ButtonPanel.h
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@class ButtonPanel;

@protocol ButtonPanelDelegate <NSObject>

-(void) ButtonPanel:(ButtonPanel*) buttonPanel ;

@end

@interface ChatMessagePanel : NSObject<UIActionSheetDelegate> {

    UINavigationController *navigationController;

    id<ButtonPanelDelegate> delegate;
}

@property(nonatomic,retain) UINavigationController *navigationController;
@property (nonatomic,retain) id<ButtonPanelDelegate> delegate;

-(void)showButtonWithNavigationController:(UINavigationController*) navigationController inView:(UIView*) view;

@end


//  ButtonPanel.m


#import "ChatMessagePanel.h"

@implementation ButtonPanel

@synthesize userListModal,delegate,navigationController;

-(void)showMessageWithNavigationController:(UINavigationController*) _navigationController inView:(UIView*) view
{
    self.navigationController = _navigationController;

    baseViewWidth = view.frame.size.width;
    baseViewHeight = view.frame.size.height;

    incomingRequestActionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:nil destructiveButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
    [incomingRequestActionSheet setActionSheetStyle:UIActionSheetStyleBlackTranslucent];
    [incomingRequestActionSheet showInView:view];


    UIButton *blockUserBttn = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 80, 40)];
    [blockUserBttn setTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"BLOCK_USERS",@"") forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [blockUserBttn setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    [blockUserBttn addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];


    UIBarButtonItem *blockUserBarBttn = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:blockUserBttn];

    [optionToolBar setItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:blockUserBarBttn, nil]];
    [incomingRequestActionSheet addSubview:optionToolBar];

}

-(void)buttonAction:(id) sender
{

}

@end
```

Answer (score -1):

> I don't think this is possible in the ios. You must have to do
>   individual for all view.

Comment: Is this helpful to you?

Comment: No, unfortunately. Thanks for trying, though! :)

Comment: I figured it out, but since it uses iOS 7 stuff, I can't post it yet. Will do once the NDA is lifted!

Answer (score -1):

You can simply add the `UIButton` on the window like

```
 [self.window addSubview:Button];
```

after `self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];`

Comment: Actually, this doesn't work - the button winds up behind all of the subviews of UIWindow, including the root view controller.

Comment: it will only go behind if the keyboard comes in front of it ... otherwise it would stay in front... Please check ....